# Can't access Reef Social area

Tags: destiny

I recently bought House of Wolves DLC and now I can't access the Vestain Outpost aka the Reef Social Area. Do I have to be a certain level? I'm level 17. I've looked everywhere on the internet. I also cant use the Dark Below or House of Wolves strikes.

Comment: Is that all you can't access? Have you tried to access multiplayer?

Comment: yes i can access multiplayer and downloadable content player vs player

Comment: Could you access these areas before?

Comment: yes i could access these area before i bought the dlc

Comment: I think I read somewhere you need to be level 24 in order to access the Reef, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: You need to be level 20. My friend accessed it when he was 21

Answer (score 0):

to access the vestian outpost you must have beaten the black garden and be level 20

Comment: This is correct as i have a lv 31 and a 17. the 17 can not access the items listed above. However beating the black garden sould be all that is required.